# REST with fiddler unauthorized

Tags: rest

I am trying to use REST in SharePoint with fiddler, but whenever I make a request I get `404 unauthorized`. So how do people test their REST requests using fiddler?

Comment: any ideas from anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People test REST endpoints in SharePoint by entering the urls directly into the browser address bar (Make sure you authenticate into SharePoint first) and reading the response text right in the browser. If Fiddler is running, it will capture the traffic as well.

Assuming you're trying to craft the endpoints directly in Fiddler's composer, the reason they don't work is they lack the appropriate authentication cookies. Using the browser handles that for you, and is easier as well.